# Add code in View with jQuery script (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have `div` in my View
`<div class="control-group" id="Phone"></div>`
and I need to add code inside with jQuery script.

I tried this

```
@section Scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("select#Role").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "2") {
            $("div#Phone").html('<span class="control-label">* Phone:</span>
                <div class="controls">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNumber)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PhoneNumber, null, new { @class = "text-error" })
          </div>');
        } else {

                }
    });
</script>
```

}

but I got a lot of errors.
What's wrong and how to fix that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below code

```
@{
var input= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNumber).ToHtmlString();
var message = Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PhoneNumber, null, new { @class = "text-error" }).ToHtmlString();

}

@section Scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("select#Role").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "2") {
            $("div#Phone").html('<span class="control-label">* Phone:</span><div class="controls">' + '@input' + '@message' + '</div>');
        } else {

                }
    });
</script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are injecting razor code into HTML. Razor code executed on server side, and it will be HTML when the server renders the page and sends to the browser. So razor code cannot run on client side. It's not a valid in HTML. Your javascript can only run client side after page rendering, because it's a client-side script. So injecting razor code by javascript doesn't make sense. What Would you like to do?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create a multi-line string in JavaScript.  To do so, I believe you need to "escape" the newline character:

```
'<span class="control-label">* Phone:</span> \
 <div class="controls"> \
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNumber) \
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PhoneNumber, null, new { @class = "text-error" }) \
 </div>'
```

You'll also want to double-check how this server-side code actually renders on the client to make sure it's what you expect and still turns out to be valid JavaScript (since you're rendering it as simply a string in a JavaScript block).